# Is there a way to separate return values using spaces or newlines in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix

I want every return value printed by a function form an array to be in new line, or separated by blank spaces. Is it possible? Here is the code snippet:

```
 function listThem() public view returns(uint[] memory) {
        return(value);
 }
```

What I get from above code are array elements separated by comma (,). I want to either have them printed in new line or separate them using blank spaces instead of commas. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi there. What do you mean "print"? Where are you printing them? In a front end?

Comment: This sparks up another question. I am coding on remix.ethereum.org (still learning) and I saw that a function declared as "view" displays the returned values below it when you click on it's button. It IS being printed right? I still have to learn about front end, but will it matter if my function is not declared view? Is it possible for front end to be able to fetch and display data from a function? Concept of "view" and clicking buttons displaying returned values because of that has got me confused, so by default, I thought a "view" function is basically printing the return value. Is that so?

Comment: A "view" function is one that doesn't modify the state of the blockchain. They are usually used to read data from a contract, rather than writing data. It doesn't have anything to do with printing the returned values. In Remix you have a debug console which displays the returned values (so yes, it prints them to the console in this case). What you generally do is have your front end (e.g. written in Javascript) call the contract, and then you can print those values - using Javascript - in the front end. Printing and formatting the output (e.g. without commas) is the job of Javascript.